# Pass ref to parent without proxy

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In my child vue component I have this referenced object that I emit to the parent:

```
const skuForm = ref({
    sku: '',
    oneTime: false,
    noDiscount: false,
    korean: false
});

const addSku = () => {
    emit('add', skuForm.value);
}
```

I want to send to the parent component the plain json object.

This is what I do in my parents component:

```
<SKUForm :open="modal" @close="modal=false" @add="addSKU"></SKUForm>


<script setup>
const addSKU = (sku) => {
    console.log('RECEIVING SKU..');
    console.log(sku);

}
```

However, the received json object is still wrapped around a proxy. How to get rid of the proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vue 3, when you use ref to create a reactive object, it returns a Proxy wrapper around the actual value.
To remove the proxy wrapper, you can use the `toRaw` function provided by Vue's Composition API.

```
import { toRaw } from 'vue'
```

and

```
const addSku = () => {
  emit('add', toRaw(skuForm.value));
};
```

Comment: I noticed that when I add multiple SKUs, the reference to the `toRaw` is always the same. So a deep copy may also be needed, at least for my usecase it was necessary.

Comment: Correct mate @Adam